# Implement int-ws:inbound-gateway

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration

How implement `<int-ws:inbound-gateway id="ws-inbound-gateway" request-channel="input"/>` with URI definition and not UriEndpointMapping defaultEndpoint`<bean class="org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.mapping.UriEndpointMapping">       <property name="defaultEndpoint" ref="ws-inbound-gateway"/></bean>`

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no any other ability to map incomming `MessageContext` to the Spring Integration `<int-ws:inbound-gateway>`, rather than an appropriate `EndpointMapping` implementation configuration.
Pay attention, please, to this one `AbstractMapBasedEndpointMapping#endpointMap` and select that implementation, which is OK for your case.
Of course, you can't use in this case `AbstractActionMethodEndpointMapping` impllementations, because there is no hook to map `<int-ws:inbound-gateway>` with annotations.